# ReferenceError: globalThis is not defined

Tags: npm, aws-amplify-cli

I have installed the npm module aws-amplify/cli globally by using the following code:

```
npm install -g @aws-amplify/cli
```

This worked, but when trying to initialise my environment using the amplify cli, it gives me the following error:

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/queue-microtask/index.js:1
ReferenceError: globalThis is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/queue-microtask/index.js:5:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:732:10)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:732:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/run-parallel/index.js:4:24)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:732:10)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:732:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/@nodelib/fs.scandir/out/providers/async.js:5:13)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:732:10)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:732:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/@nodelib/fs.scandir/out/index.js:4:15)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:732:10)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:732:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/@nodelib/fs.walk/out/readers/async.js:4:19)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:732:10)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:732:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/@nodelib/fs.walk/out/providers/async.js:3:17)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:732:10)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:732:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/@nodelib/fs.walk/out/index.js:4:17)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:732:10)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:732:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/fast-glob/out/readers/stream.js:5:16)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:732:10)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:732:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/fast-glob/out/providers/async.js:3:18)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:732:10)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:732:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/fast-glob/out/index.js:3:17)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:732:10)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:732:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/globby/index.js:5:18)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:732:10)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:732:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/amplify-category-function/lib/provider-utils/awscloudformation/utils/packageLayer.js:21:34)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:732:10)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:732:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/amplify-category-function/lib/provider-utils/awscloudformation/utils/layerParams.js:13:24)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:732:10)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:732:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/amplify-category-function/lib/provider-utils/awscloudformation/index.js:7:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:732:10)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:732:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/amplify-category-function/lib/index.js:13:29)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:732:10)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:732:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/lib/extensions/amplify-helpers/update-amplify-meta.js:34:37)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:732:10)
    at AmplifyToolkit.get updateamplifyMetaAfterResourceAdd [as updateamplifyMetaAfterResourceAdd] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/lib/domain/amplify-toolkit.js:229:17)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/amplify-category-auth/lib/provider-utils/awscloudformation/utils/amplify-meta-updaters.js:48:21
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/next_tick.js:81:5)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue with an eslint rule. Read the fix here: https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/15199#issuecomment-948724014

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Consider updating your version of node.js to `>=12`.

`globalThis` was added in node.js v12.0.0 according to [this compatibility table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/globalThis#browser_compatibility).

<sub>**Note:** Also refer to [issue #17](https://github.com/feross/queue-microtask/issues/17) in the GitHub repo for `queue-microtask` where this issue has been reported.</sub>

Comment: fixed with node 12.14.0. I use nvm so that command is `nvm install 12.14.0`

Answer (score 0):

For me solved by updating [pm2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2)

```bash
npm install pm2 -g
pm2 update
```