# yarn begin error Command failed with exit code 1

Tags: react-scripts, yarnpkg-v2

> Tried to use yarn begin, but errors keep showing up

> PS C:\Users\obi besong\Desktop\appC> yarn begin

````
yarn run v1.22.17
$ react-scripts start
C:\Users\obi besong\Desktop\appC\node_modules\queue-microtask\index.js:5
  ? queueMicrotask.bind(globalThis)
                        ^

ReferenceError: globalThis is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Salathiel Ojage\Desktop\contestMungwin\node_modules\queue-microtask\index.js:5:25)     
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:805:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:816:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:672:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:612:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:604:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:711:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:14:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Salathiel Ojage\Desktop\contestMungwin\node_modules\run-parallel\index.js:4:24)        
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:805:30)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.```
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ReferenceError: globalThis is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66586352/referenceerror-globalthis-is-not-defined)

Comment: Yes it does, I am grateful